# Import data with pgfplotstable and generic horizontal lines

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a dataset which is in the following form:

```
# timeIt newtonIt globalIt time_0 time_1
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
1 1 1 0.01247044 0.01111968
1 2 2 0.0216411 0.006752475
1 3 3 0.01974868 0.005811811
1 4 4 0.01794313 0.005261905
1 5 5 0.01629763 0.004712679
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
2 1 6 0.01494174 0.004345911
2 2 7 0.01421942 0.003821437
2 3 8 0.01349764 0.003648206
2 4 9 0.01321967 0.003509467
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
3 1 10 0.01330905 0.003477882
3 2 11 0.01312566 0.003279321
3 3 12 0.0130273 0.00319411
3 4 13 0.01304904 0.003214647
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

I'd like to import this with `pgfplotstable` and it would be very convenient if I could transfer this appearance to the table in my document. Notice that the blocks have a different number of lines.

Is there a way to tell pgfplots that the commented lines (which could also be blank or any other delimiter type) should be used as `\midrules`?

Comment: Is it the first column that decides the rules?

Comment: Yes, the first column increments by 1 in each block.

Comment: Maybe you can add a `\myparser` at the head of every line and define it as `\myparser#1{\ifhashtag...}` or so...

Comment: @Symbol1 Sounds like a start, but unfortunately are my LaTeX skills not so well developed that I could just start and implement something like this. Is there a chance that you have any examples?